# overriding run() method in Thread subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I am just wondering what the result would be if I subclassed a class which extends `Thread` and I wrote following code and tested:

```
class A extends Thread {
    public A() {
        this.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" in A " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" in B " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

public class OverrideRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
    }    
}
```

And the result is:

> in A Thread-0
>   in B Thread-1

But I don't understand why two threads are created?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `B b = new B();` statement calls no argument parameter of class `B` and that calls no argument parameter constructor(Default) of class `A`.

This is due to constructor chaining.

Answer (score 2):

That's because *you* created two threads (two objects inherited from `Thread`), here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A(); // #1
    B b = new B(); // #2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> but i don't understand why two threads are created ?

Two threads are started because you are starting them in the `A()` constructor:

```
public A() {
    this.start();
}
```

and you are constructing two objects -- an `A` and a `B` which extends `A`:

```
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
```

By default, when you say `new B()` since it does not have a no-arg constructor, it will call the no-arg constructor of the superclass.  So it will call the `A` constructor which starts the thread.  See [Java documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).  To quote:

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.

As an aside, it is not good practice to start a thread inside of it's constructor.  There are some thread race conditions that can happen when you do this.  It is much better to call `a.start()` after you call `new A()`.  Also, it is a better pattern to define a class that implements `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.  So your code should be:

```
class A implements Runnable() {
     public A() {
         // don't start it here
     }
     public void run() {
         ...
     }
}
...

Thread a = new Thread(new A());
a.start();
Thread b = new Thread(new B());
b.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

`A` extends `Thread`, `B` extends `A`, so when you create an instance of `A` and an instance of `B`, you've created two instances of `Thread`.

Note that it's generally preferred *not* to extend `Thread`, but instead to *just* implement `Runnable` - then pass that `Runnable` to the `Thread(Runnable)` constructor. This ends up being cleaner from a design point of view - you're not really trying to change the threading behaviour, you're just giving it a different task to execute.

(It's also generally better to use the facilities in java.util.concurrent instead of creating threads directly in the first place, but there we go...)

Answer (score 1):

2 threads are getting created because you are asking for it by running the following lines:

```
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
```